# Accessing files and folders in WebPartLibrary in Sharepoint Online using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, sharepoint-online

My main aim is read and modify files e.g. Excel which currently sit in Sharepoint Online. However, the files sit in a WebPartLibrary item created within a Sharepoint Online. I was only able to retrieve a link to the webPart i.e. .ASPX driveItem using Microsoft Graph convention.

My question is how can I access folders, sub-folders and eventually files in this WebPart? Is it possible to do so only by using Microsoft Graph API or other such as REST API are used to achieve such task?

Comment: The WebPartLibrary is not intended to be accessed via MS Graph. It's an internal repo where web part configuration files are stored, and shouldn't be where a web part is storing state that would be updated like this. Can you give me more details about your scenario?

Comment: @RyanGregg In my situation, in Sharepoint Online, folders and files are constructed as web parts. I simply wanted to access various folders and sub-folders, and their files such as Excel workbooks. I believe MS Graph cannot access those files over there, thus, I will resort to using Sharepoint client API and REST commands for this purpose. Please, correct me if I am wrong.